# Как сделать чтобы один поток дожидался другого?

Tags: java, android, json

Я знаю, как взять из страницы её содержимое, распарсить и получить нужную строку. К слову, вот он:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MusicRepository.SongDownload songDownload = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build().create(MusicRepository.SongDownload.class);
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            if (songDownload != null) {
                obj = songDownload.getSongs(playingSong.mp3id, playingSong.hash).execute().body().get(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<Object> list = GSON.fromJson(GSON.toJson(obj), TPE);
        if (list != null) {
            ssrc = list.get(2).toString(); // Получаю ссылку
        }
    }
}, 0);
```

Мне надо сделать метод, благодаря которого я смогу возвращать сею ссылку. Ибо, из одного потока нельзя передавать в другой данные, то подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы главный поток дождался того, что парсит страницу и когда всё закончилось, то метод в главном потоке возвратил значение.

Comment: runOnUiThread(() -> { });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если решать данную задачу нативными средствами Android, то я бы смотрел в сторону Handler'ов.
В Вашем случае можно сделать так:

1. Запустить отдельный поток, который парсит страницу.
2. Получить Looper главного потока и прикрепить ему Handdler
3. Производить общение между потоками через Handler. Все сообщения внутри handleMessage будут обрабатываться внутри главного потока (если получен Looper главного потока)

Вот хорошая статься про Handler'ы: https://medium.com/@manishgiri/android-handler-tutorial-ccda6994f01c

Answer (score 2):

> метод в главном потоке возвратил значение.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

interface ListenerLink {
    void onLink(String link);
}

void getLink(ListenerLink listener) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override public void run() {
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
                listener.onLink("my link");
            });
        }
    }, 100);
}

getLink(new ListenerLink() {
    @Override public void onLink(String link) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), link, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```